# Apenas construtores sem parâmetros e initializers são suportados no LINQ to Entities - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia cursos. O aluno, ao entrar na tela de inscrição e clicar no botão "inscrição", é associado a um curso, ou seja, fica inscrito. Até aí tudo certo, só que quando eu tento fazer o tratamento para verificar se ele já está inscrito em um curso, porque se ele estiver inscrito não pode se inscrever novamente no mesmo curso, o sistema deve barrar, mas ao tentar fazer esse tratamento me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Apenas construtores sem parâmetros e initializers são suportados no LINQ to Entities

**Action Inscrição**

```
    //GET
    public ActionResult Inscricao()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        return View(db.Cursos.Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null)));

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
    {
        Aluno aluno;

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }


        return View(db.Cursos.Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null)));

    }
```

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.CursoInscricoes>

<h2>Lista de Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Ementa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalaviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.Curso.Id" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: {inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid")},
                    success: function() {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Coloque as classes models também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evite de fazer coisas assim no seu código:

```
return View(
    db.Cursos.Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(
        c, 
        db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null)
    )
);
```

Apesar de parecer mais simples ser sucinto na hora de criar novos objetos, o Entity Framework não trabalha muito bem com esta construção, justamente porque tenta converter toda a expressão em SQL. No seu caso, está claro que o intuito não é o de fazer tudo virar SQL, e sim, apenas uma parte disso.

Procure separar o que será executado como SQL do que não será. Para esta expressão, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
var cursos = db.Cursos.Include(c => c.AlunoCurso).ToList();
var cursoInscricoes = new List<CursoInscricoes>();
foreach (var curso in cursos) 
{
    foreach (var alunoCurso in curso.AlunoCursos)
        cursoInscricoes.Add(new CursoInscricoes {
            Curso = curso,
            AlunoCurso = alunoCurso
    });
}

return View(cursoIscricoes);
```

Apesar de ser uma construção mais prolixa, é mais correto segmentar o código desta forma.

Answer (score 1):

No seu retorno, mude:

```
db.Cursos.Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null))
```

Para:

```
db.Cursos.ToList().Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null))
```

Como a mensagem de erro está acusando, somente é possível utilizar Construtores sem parâmetro com Linq to Entities. Então retorno do banco primeiro (`.ToList()`) e depois construa o objeto do tipo `CursoInscricoes`.

Comment: Fiz a alteração @MarcusVinicius, mas agora estou tendo esse erro:  **"Não é possível criar um valor constante do tipo 'MeuProjeto.Models.Aluno'. Só tipos ou tipos de enumeração primitivo são suportados neste contexto."**