# Erro - Só tipos ou tipos de enumeração primitivo são suportados neste contexto em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Conforme explicações deste link [Apenas construtores sem parâmetros e initializers são suportados no LINQ to Entities](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67806/apenas-construtores-sem-par%C3%A2metros-e-initializers-s%C3%A3o-suportados-no-linq-to-enti/67823#67823)

```
return View(db.Cursos.ToList().Select(c => new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null)));
```

Fiz minhas alterações só que me deparei com outro erro.
**Erro: NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code**
**Não é possível criar um valor constante do tipo 'MeuProjeto.Models.Aluno'. Só tipos ou tipos de enumeração primitivo são suportados neste contexto."** 
O erro cai nesse trecho do código aqui `new CursoInscricoes(c, db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Aluno.Equals(aluno) && ac.Curso.Equals(c)) != null)));` Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucioná-lo?!

**Model Aluno**

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Models {
public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Nome é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O campo Nome deve ter no mínimo 4 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "CPF")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo CPF é obrigatório")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [CPFAtributo]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RG")]
    public string RG { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo E-mail é obrigatório")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Endereço de e-mail informado não é válido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O campo Usuário deve ter no mínimo 4 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Usuário é obrigatório")]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Senha é obrigatório")]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Celular")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um número de Celular")]
    public string Telefone_Celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Endereço é obrigatório")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um Estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Matrícula")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a Matrícula")]
    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Perfil { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; }

    public Aluno()
    {

    }

}
```

}

**Model AlunoCurso**

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Models {
public class AlunoCurso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AlunoId { get; set; }

    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    public bool Aprovado { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
}}
```

**Essa Minha Classe CursoInscricoes**

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Models {
public class CursoInscricoes
{
    public Curso Curso { get; set; }

    public bool Inscrito { get; set; }

    public CursoInscricoes(Curso curso, bool inscrito)
    {
        this.Curso = curso;
        this.Inscrito = inscrito;
    }}
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de `MeuProjeto.Models.Aluno`? Se for um tipo complexo (e.g., uma classe - `public class Aluno`), então o EF não sabe como comparar objetos desse tipo, como a mensagem está dizendo.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta meus Models e classe CursoInscricoes <- essa classe não persiste no banco. @carlosfigueira.